# Setting Heat Map Color range as per given Sequence in hcharter

Tags: r, heatmap, r-highcharter

Here I am trying to create a heat map using `highcharter::hcharter()` where **less than -1** should be one color (pink), **-1 to 1** should be transparent or white color, and **greater than +1** should be another color (violet).

Presently I have written code using `hchart()` and used `color_stops` to change the color format. But this works really well when data is centered to 0, but when it isn't centered to 0 let say from **-5 to +7.5** white/transparent color would be shifted to 1 as shown in the image below.

```
a1 <- rnorm(30,0,2)  
a2 <- rnorm(30,0,2)  
a3 <- rnorm(30,0,2)  
a4 <- rnorm(30,0,2)  
a <- cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4)
heatmap_matrix <- as.matrix(a)

library(highcharter) 
hchart(heatmap_matrix) %>%  
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(n = 3, colors = c("#FF1493", "white", "#800080")))
```

For data range between `-5 to +7.5`
-5  to -1 should show pink gradient color
-1 to +1 should show white color
+1 to 7.5 should show violet gradient color

[image: Heat Map sample plot using hcharter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument `stops` in `hc_colorAxis()` requires a list that defines the minimum value as **0** and the maximum value as **1**. You can set a number within 0 ~ 1 to represent the position of a certain value and set its color.

**Find where the zero is located**

[image: foo+bar]

```
p <- (0 - min(heatmap_matrix)) / (max(heatmap_matrix) - min(heatmap_matrix))
```

**Set a custom list**

```
stops <- data.frame(q = c(0, p, 1),
                    c = c("#FF1493", "#FFFFFF", "#800080"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#          q       c
# 1 0.000000 #FF1493
# 2 0.434873 #FFFFFF
# 3 1.000000 #800080

stops <- list_parse2(stops)
```

**Control arguments**

```
hchart(heatmap_matrix) %>%  
  hc_colorAxis(stops = stops, startOnTick = F, endOnTick = F)
```

[image]