# How to assign heatmap color range

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to draw a two-color heatmap with a range from **-2 to 6, and 0 is in white**.
my code is giving me a symmetric color range and apparently my heatmap is too light. 
I tried to use `symbreaks = F` but then 0 is not white; I also tried manually assign two colors but its not working either.

```
colfunc1 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Blues"))
colfunc2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Reds"))
hmcols <- c(colfunc1(25), colfunc2(25*(max(data) - 1)))
```

this is the code I used to generate the following heatmap. 
Please advise! **Thank you!**

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(data), Colv=FALSE, scale = T, dendrogram = "row", trace = "none",
          col = hmcol, key = T, cexCol = 1.5, cexRow = 1, srtCol = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve]. You'll get more help, faster, that way.

Comment: You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820143/how-to-change-heatmap-2-color-range-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54143215/10068985) I answered. It's about heatmaps in `highcharter` package. The difference is that `highcharter` is more convenient to assign colors. I use the same concept to solve this `heatmap.2` case.

**Sample Data**

```
x <- rnorm(1000, 2, 1.5)
x[x < -2] <- -2
x[x > 6] <- 6
mat <- matrix(x, 20, 50)
```

**Description**

First, use `symkey = F, symbreaks = F` in `heatmap.2` can make the color-key asymmetric. And then, you need to find where the specified value (i.e. 0) is located in your data. By the following formula, you can get a value within 0 ~ 1 to represent the position of a certain value.

[image: foo+bar]

In this case, `(0-(-2))/(6-(-2))` is 0.25. If there are 100 breakpoints, then you need to concatenate `100 * 0.25 = 25` red colors and `100 - 25 = 75` blue colors. You can find that the white color will be consistent with zero.

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)

hmcol <- function(n){
  colfun1 <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "Reds")))
  colfun2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))
  p <- (0 - min(mat)) / (max(mat) - min(mat))
  gap <- n * p
  c(colfun1(floor(gap)), colfun2(n - gap))
}

heatmap.2(mat, trace = "none", symkey = F, symbreaks = F, col = hmcol(50))
```

You can set any number in `hmcol()` to indicate the number of breakpoints.(You can try `col = hmcol(10)` and `col = hmcol(100)` to see the difference.)

[image]